# AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError in PagesController#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I've pulled up a few past SO posts on similar errors but non of which listed had my exact case where it was the /desktop /Desktop case difference... this error started occurring out of no where for me as well running my app locally.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated:  (SO won't let me post screen shot for lack of reputation points)  but here is the error the browser pulls up:

```
AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError in    PagesController#home

        Missing helper file         helpers//users/myname/desktop/versions/app/helpers/actual_expenses_helper.rb_helper.rb

        Extracted source (around line #1):

        class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
        # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
        # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
        protect_from_forgery with: :exception
        before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

        Rails.root: /Users/myname/Desktop/versions/app

        Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
        app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

---

I did run pwd to compare the path with the irb ( File.expand_path("./") )  path and the only case difference was again in the  /desktop   vs    /Desktop  part.... any clue what I should do? Can I even rename desktop without causing big problems?

Comment: Is the file which stores your helper supposed to be `actual_expenses_helper.rb_helper.rb`?

Comment: i don't think so.... i see the redundancy with the double  _helper.rb  but not sure what's going on there....

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with several rubyist regarding this nebulous error / situation,  the only solution was the re-clone the repo to a new folder and rid of the old...some how the paths got really really screwed up :\